# SDL2 not triggering on keys in terminal?

Tags: rust, sdl-2, keyboard-events

I'm currently using sdl2 (0.35.2) in a Rust application to detect Key Events but it seems to only be triggering for the Event::Quit and nothing else. I have a very simple example like this

```
use sdl2;
use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;

fn main() {

    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();

    'event_loop:loop {
        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
                Event::Quit { .. } => {
                    println!("Quit"); break 'event_loop;
                },
                Event::KeyDown { keycode:Some(Keycode::Escape), .. } => {
                    println!("Escape"); break 'event_loop;
                },
                Event::KeyDown { .. } => {
                    println!("KeyDown Triggered");
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But both of the Event:KeyDown matches never trigger, only able to get Event::Quit to trigger with `Ctrl+C`. I'm doing this on Debian in a basic terminal.

Comment: Not a Rust guy but where are you creating a window?  SDL only supports input events on windows, not the terminal.

Comment: I'm not using a window, bugger is that why it doesn't work?

Comment: SDL 1.2 had [back](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/tree/main/src/video/aalib)-[ends](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/tree/main/src/video/caca) for [AAlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib) & [libcaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libcaca) but [it looks like](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/release-2.26.x/src/video) they didn't port it forward to SDL2 :(  So yeah: create a window, drop back to SDL 1.2, or port SDL 1.2's AAlib/libcaca backends to SDL2.

Comment: Thanks a bunch though, you've saved me a lot of debugging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [SDL2 backends](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/release-2.26.x/src/video) require creating a `SDL_Window` to receive keyboard events; they don't handle console/terminal input.

SDL 1.2 has [back](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/tree/main/src/video/aalib)-[ends](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL-1.2/tree/main/src/video/caca) for [AAlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib) & [libcaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libcaca) but they weren't ported forward to SDL2 :(

Options:

- Create a window.
- Drop back to SDL 1.2.
- Port SDL 1.2's AAlib/libcaca backends to SDL2.